# Navigation View Global Action Back State

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-navigationview, android-jetpack-navigation

I have been messing with the Jetpack Navigation component, and I created an activity that uses a navigation drawer.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val navigationController = findNavController(R.id.navigationHostFragment)
        navigationView.setupWithNavController(navigationController)

        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(TOP_LEVEL_DESTINATIONS, drawerLayout)
        toolbar.setupWithNavController(navigationController, appBarConfiguration)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean =
            NavigationUI.navigateUp(findNavController(R.id.navigationHostFragment), drawerLayout)

}
```

This works as I would expect, but then I added a [global action](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-global-action) for the settings screen.

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    app:startDestination="@id/appBarFragment">

    ...

    <activity android:id="@+id/settingsActivity"
        android:name="com.example.app.ui.SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_settings"/>

    <action android:id="@+id/settingsAction"
        app:destination="@+id/settingsActivity"/>

</navigation>
```

And reference the action in the `NavigationView` menu.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    ...

    <group android:id="@+id/navigationGroupSettings">

        <item android:id="@+id/aboutAction"
            android:title="@string/title_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_black_24dp"/>

        <item android:id="@+id/settingsAction"
            android:title="@string/title_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"/>

    </group>

</menu>
```

This displays the `SettingsActivity`, but when I press the back button to return to the `MainActivity` the first destination is displayed, rather than the previous destination. Even though the `NavigationView` saves its state correctly, and has the last destination checked (instead of the first item in the list).

I also tried replacing the `SettingsActivity` with a `SettingsFragment`, with the same result.

How do I get the navigation component to correctly save its state after a global action is selected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [`onNavDestinationSelected()` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI.html#onNavDestinationSelected(android.view.MenuItem,%2520androidx.navigation.NavController)) (which is how [NavigationUI triggers menu items](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#Tie-navdrawer)):

> By default, the back stack will be popped back to the navigation graph's start destination. Menu items that have `android:menuCategory="secondary"` will not pop the back stack.

Therefore you can add `android:menuCategory="secondary"` to your menu item if you'd like to avoid popping other destinations off the stack when you select your settings destination.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - is there any reasonable argument why this is not default behavior? To me, this is completely not intuitive. Anyway, thanks for this answer!

Comment: Thank you, I had the same issue with DrawerLayout and BottomNavigation, that the state of the bottom navigation got lost when using the drawer layout to navigate to a screen and then using the back button.